# How to remove noble prisoners from dead factions?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I captured a lord after a battle, and shortly thereafter my faction wiped their faction off the map. There is no way to release a noble prisoner that I'm aware of. So I'm still stuck with Sanjar Khan who nobody will pay for and he doesn't ever seem to try to escape like other lords normally do (Wiki says every 48 hours they make an attempt - I've had him for at least a month now).

I'm guessing this is a bug... so is there some way (e.g. hacking save files) to get rid of this useless prisoner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing a bit longer, I finally received fiefdom of a city and was able to leave him in the dungeon there.

Now I'm just wondering if he is removed permanently from the game, since shortly thereafter, the castle was raided by another faction ;)